# Get the string backward until it hit certain character

Tags: c#

Sorry if this question has been asked before. But I am unable to find it.

Is there actually a way to get and cut the string from backwards until it hit certain char ?

This is currently a working code.

```
string path = "LivingOrganism/Animal/Bird/Chicken.exe";
public void SomeFunc()
{
    //count the string from the back until it hit the seperator
        string[] splitted = path.Split(new string[] { "/" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList().ToArray();
        string combineStr = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < splitted.Count()-1; i++)
                combineStr += splitted[i] += "/";

        path = combineStr;
        print("results: " + path);
}
```

So everytime `SomeFunc()` is called;

first call is LivingOrganism/Animal/Bird/

second call is LivingOrganism/Animal/

third call is LivingOrganism/

fourth call is

which is what i intended to do.

however, is there actually a way to optimize this. ?
feels kinda ugly that i need to split the char first and the recombine them in forloop

Comment: Use `LastIndexOf` and `Substring`?

Comment: path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf("/"))

Comment: @AJITH That will find the `/` at the end of `LivingOrganism/Animal/Bird/`, which isn't what OP wants. `LastIndexOf` however takes a parameter saying where to start

Comment: I havent really heard of LastIndexof and substring. Can you maybe give example ?

Comment: See the documentation for some starting examples: [`LastIndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=net-7.0#system-string-lastindexof(system-char-system-int32)), [`Substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-7.0#system-string-substring(system-int32-system-int32))

Comment: I support your question, but also suspect it's an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). (Almost perfectly matches the first example on the website, too). Are you actually trying to get the path to a parent folder in a directory? There may be better ways to do that than parsing and cutting slashes in a string.

Comment: You should use `Path.GetDirectoryName` if you just want to parse a file path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [`LastIndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=net-7.0#system-string-lastindexof(system-char-system-int32)) and [`Substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-7.0). Something like the following:

```
void SomeFunc1()
{
    string result;
    if (path.Length == 0)
    {
        result = path;
    }
    else
    {
        var lastIndexOf = path.LastIndexOf("/",path.Length - 2);
        result = lastIndexOf switch
        {
            >= 0 => path.Substring(0, lastIndexOf + 1),
            _ => string.Empty
        };
    }
    Console.WriteLine("results: " + result);
    path = result;
}
```

Note that `System.IO` provides path manipulation functions so you can also try just:

```
void SomeFunc1()
{
    path = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
    Console.WriteLine(path);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet that should work. There are probably better solutions.

```
string path = "LivingOrganism/Animal/Bird/Chicken.exe";
    public void SomeFunc()
    {
        for(int i=path.Length-1;i>=0;i--){
            if(path[i] == '/' || i==0){
                path = path.Remove(i);
                break;
            }
        }
            Console.WriteLine("results: " + path);
    }
```

Comment: Ack, right you are. My bad. This is still implementing `string.LastIndexOf` by hand, but less efficiently, though

Comment: No problem :) also happens to me sometimes ^^ . I just tried to understand what the problem is